# Перегрузка функции с аргументами по умолчанию

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy

У меня есть функция, которая в зависимости от bool-аргумента возвращает тот или иной тип, наподобие такой:

```py
from typing import Union
def foo(num: int = 1, as_bytes: bool = False) -> Union[str, bytes]:
    rv = str(num)
    return rv.encode("utf-8") if as_bytes else rv

foo(1, False)  # Revealed type is 'Union[builtins.str, builtins.bytes]'
foo(as_bytes=True)  # Revealed type is 'Union[builtins.str, builtins.bytes]'
```

Я хочу написать [аннотации для перегрузки функции](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/more_types.html#function-overloading) так, чтобы mypy понимал, какой именно тип возвращается в зависимости от значения аргумента:

```
foo(1, False)  # Revealed type is 'builtins.str'
foo(as_bytes=True)  # Revealed type is 'builtins.bytes'
```

Самое лучшее, что у меня получилось написать — это вот такое:

```py
from typing import Union, Literal, overload
@overload
def foo(num: int = 1, as_bytes: Literal[False] = False) -> str: ...
@overload
def foo(num: int = 1, as_bytes: Literal[True] = True) -> bytes: ...
@overload
def foo(num: int = 1, as_bytes: bool = False) -> Union[str, bytes]: ...
```

Но проблема в том, что mypy в таком случае ругается ошибкой «Overloaded function signatures 1 and 2 overlap with incompatible return types». И это вполне логично, ведь вызов `foo()` будет соответствовать двум разным сигнатурам. Однако я так и не придумал, как это исправить. Если попытаться написать `as_bytes: Literal[True] = False`, то ругается ошибкой «Incompatible default for argument», что тоже логично.

Как правильно написать эти аннотации, если это вообще возможно?

Comment: P.S. 1) Принимаются варианты более удачной формулировки заголовка 2) Что делать с меткой «типизация»?

Comment: А если из 1-ой или 2-ой перегрузки удалить значение по умолчанию дня `as_bytes`?

Comment: @ioprst SyntaxError: non-default argument follows default argument

Comment: попробуйте для `num` тоже убрать, из 1-ой и 2-ой

Comment: @ioprst тогда mypy ошибок не пишет, но определяет типы неправильно (Union вместо конкретного типа)

Comment: последний вариант попробуйте: https://ideone.com/lB5UYU

Comment: @ioprst пишет сразу обе ошибки, упомянутые в вопросе

Comment: получилось добиться нужного варианта?

Comment: @AndreyMaslov не особо, я уже забыл, зачем мне это было нужно)

Answer (score 0):

Получился такой вариант

```
from typing import Union, Literal, overload


@overload
def foo(num: int = 1) -> str:  ...
@overload
def foo(*, as_bytes: Literal[True]) -> bytes:  ...
@overload
def foo(*, as_bytes: Literal[False]) -> str:  ...
@overload
def foo(num: int, as_bytes: Literal[True]) -> bytes: ...
@overload
def foo(num: int, as_bytes: Literal[False]) -> str: ...


def foo(num: int = 1, as_bytes: bool = False) -> Union[str, bytes]:
    rv = str(num)
    return rv.encode("utf-8") if as_bytes else rv



s = foo(1, False)
b = foo(as_bytes=True)
s2 = foo(1)
```

вроде не выдает ошибок и правильно определяет все типы